# memory problems when migrating to Visual Studio 2017 from 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compilation, visual-studio-2017

i have a relative big C++ project which i can compile in vs2015 with no problems at all, 
when i tried to compiled it in vs2017 i get the problem:

```
fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
```

when monitoring the cl.exe process it gets to 3.5G and then crush with this message,
the compiled application is x64 but the compiler is by default 32bit

after some googling i added this flag:

```
set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64
devenv.exe
```

and its used the 64bit compiler which works but suck all my memory (30G+) and make compilation super slow... :(

why its happening and what can i do ? in vs2015 exactly same project was compiling at no time and almost no memory consumption at all (relatively)

thanks for any help!

(P.S  i tried the /zm200 /zm1000 /zm2000 flags, doesnt seems to change anything)

Comment: What version of VS are you suing? The latest are better than older versions (currently at 15.9)

Comment: Try updating VS2017 (click the flag near upper right corner). If that doesn't help I think you should run the compiler with as much messages dumped as possible and post a bug to MS !

Comment: im on vs2017 15.8.7